# Does Istio automatically balance CPU utilization over replicas before applyng load balancing policy?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I've deployed [Boutique online](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/microservices-demo) on a cluster for some performance tests with and without istio enabled; I've also setted an HPA.
Here I focus my attention on productcatalogservice deployment (other deployments that scale on multiple replicas, except frontend, have perhaps the same behaviour).
After app deploying on my cluster, I've created its own HPA with command:

```
kubectl autoscale deploy productcatalogservice --cpu-percent=80 --min=1 --max=4
```

so, when a productcatalogservice pod achieves 80% of request CPU, it scales from 1 to maximum 4 replicas. I've done similar command for all other app deployments and I've started a jmeter stress test that simulates users navigation on boutique. That's what happen displayed by grafana:
[productcatalogservice CPU utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIyrM.jpg)

I think this unbalanced CPU utilization is due by default kube pseudo-roundrobin policy, first replica (the old one) have a lot of old work to do plus a fraction of new one that is splitted equally over replicas.
After I've done a second stress test, the same as before, but now with istio sidecars enabled on the namespace. By default istio load balancing policy over replicas is roundrobin so I espect to see the same situation as before, but grafana show me this: [productcatalogservice CPU utilization with istio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucCpd.jpg)

The fact that now there are 3 replicas is due probably by istio overhead but isn't it the point; now CPU utilization is balanced. Wow this is surprising and good to see, but why does it happen? Maybe istio force something in its algoritm to balance CPU utilization and then apply roundrobin policy?

UPDATE
I've done other tests with various hpa percentage (from 30% to up to 100%) and the situation is still the same. Istio always balaces cpu utilization.

UPDATE 2:
Probably the problem can be due to gRPC long lived connection that bypass service load balancing across replicas.
https://learnk8s.io/kubernetes-long-lived-connections

Comment: Did you clean up the resources before second test? Was it one time spike during 1st test?

Comment: Yes, probably the issue was due by hpa percentage. Sidecars make pods more heavy so, with same hpa percenage, they scale and converge earlier into a balanced scenario.